# php and xml: finding an xml node and then using its value in php

Tags: php, xml, xpath, nodes

My problem is that I can't find a way to find a node in my XML document 
this is it (`users.xml`):

```
<users>

    <user>
        <id>10</id>
        <username>User1</username>
    </user>
    <user>
        <id>22</id>
        <username>User2</username>
    </user>
    <user>
        <id>13</id>
        <username>User3</username>
    </user>
</users>
```

In a `$_SESSION['username']` I have the username of currently logged user. I want to use `xpath` or something else to assign the id of a logged user (let's say User2 is logged) to the variable `$userID`. Can someone help me out, because so far all I've been getting were errors.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What kind of errors? It helps if you add that to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the DOMXpath::evaluate() method.

Get the `user` elements:

`/users/user`

Only with specific `username` child element:

`/users/user[username = "User2"]`

The `id` child elements of the found users:

`/users/user[username = "User2"]/Id`

Cast first found `id` element to string

`string(/users/user[username = "User2"]/Id)`

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<users>
    <user>
        <id>10</id>
        <username>User1</username>
    </user>
    <user>
        <id>22</id>
        <username>User2</username>
    </user>
    <user>
        <id>13</id>
        <username>User3</username>
    </user>
</users>
XML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$userName = 'User2';
$userId = $xpath->evaluate('string(/users/user[username = "'.$userName.'"]/id)');

var_dump($userId);
```

Output

```
string(2) "22"
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this can be useful for you to read the contents of the nodes  childes but 'is in Italian:

http://www.edinweb.altervista.org/2013/10/16/leggere-xml-con-simplexml/

**edit** extracting the main points from the link:

For example, if you have the following XML file `books.xml` (a list of books):

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<books>
  <book id="1">
     <title>La Divina Commedia</title>
     <author>Dante Alighieri</author>
</book>
<book id="2">
     <title>I Promessi Sposi</title>
     <author>Alessandro Manzoni</author>
</book>
<book id="3">
     <title>I Malavoglia</title>
     <author>Giovanni Verga</author>
</book>
</libri>
```

As you can see, this is a list of books, with title and author for each book.

With the Xpath method we can search in the XML document with the Xpath language which is a W3C standard. For example, to access the book with id=2:

```
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("books.xml");

$arr = $xml->xpath("/books/book[@id=2]");
//array that contains the information relating to the book with id=2
 print_r($arr);
?>
```

There are further examples at the link above - hopefully, with this bit of translation you will be able to make sense of the other code examples given there.

Comment: I posted a link in Italian that I know for that problem, it will be 'the google translate, I do not understand the phrase "btw That site is playing an awfull video"?

thanks

Comment: Hmmm, that makes your answer not so usefull, do you think? And now I have to do the awfull google translate and my italian is really below any acceptable level. You could really help if you simply cut-paste and translate just the relevant pieces in your answer. That makes your answer direct useable for future visitors. Isn't that we should strive for here? (the site played me a video that I couldn't get rid off quickly so that annoyed me a little bit, thats all)